# Application architecture suggestion required

Tags: asp.net, angular, architecture

Currently we are working on large scale angular application. As per our servers and security architecture, we have three servers assume **A | B | C (Client)**. Now A server has all database and all firewall rules and some specific ports open and outside world cannot access server A directly, which means C (Client) cannot access server A directly. We have to go through server B. and then server B make request to server A and send the response to C.

> If above is making sense to you.

As per our current architecture, we have added WCF Service to Server A and WebApi to Server B and exposing the WCF service through Service Contract as an Interface and Client Factory.

Now we making to HTTP Request through our Angular Client (C Server) to server B and then B forward that request to server A after perform some request validation rules and provide us the output. I just want to know are we following the right approach. Having a WCF Service seems we are using some outdated approach. We are totally depend on Microsoft technologies on back end.

What are the other options we can try here.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your architecture is ok and you are right when you say that WCF Service seems outdated.
I use a similar architecture but instead of WCF Service I use RESTful services provided by a NET CORE 2.0 api.

For my project I started from this template: [QuickApp - ASP.NET Core/Angular5 Project Template](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adentum.QuickApp-ASPNETCoreAngularXProjectTemplate.).

This application consists of:

- Template pages using Angular5 and TypeScript
- RESTful API Backend using ASP.NET Core MVC Web API
- Database using Entity Framework Core
- Authentication based on OpenID Connect
- API Documentation using Swagger
- Angular CLI for managing client-side libraries
- Theming using Bootstrap

This template use a single project for the api (the Net Core controlles classes) and the client (the Angular client app) but separating them will be very simple.

Into the template you can se the use of [AutoMapper](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html) for the object-object mapper. It's usefult in the controller when you use a 'ViewModel' class instead of the model class. A ViewModel is a container-type class, which represents only the data you want to display on your web page.

I also suggest you to use [Autofact](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to manage dependency injection.

Comment: Can you share some link with example. Where I can read more about it

Comment: @RaviMittal I insert into the answer the reference to the template from which I started. It's a great project

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much sounds like the API-Gateway pattern often found within microservice architectures.
Take a look at this page: http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html

Usually, the implementation of such a gateway is lightweight and simple, I agree that WCF is not the right option. You might be better off building a simple ASP.NET Core REST endpoint that redirects your requests to server A.